# PostgreSQL returns unrecognized configuration error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not sure why PostgreSQL returns below error for one of my script, but not for second one:

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "context_info" SQL state:
>   42704

The only difference in **WORKING** script is, I have removed one element from **IN** function.

**WORKING**

```
select distinct(t2.graph_id) from quad_text_no_ga t2 where t2.subject = t2.graph_id and t2.
subject_type in ('http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#industry','
http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#xraypanelsize','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#countryregion','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productgroup','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#report','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#salesdocumentstatus','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#erppriceitemwhitelist',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#approvalrule',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#triggeraction',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productmrptype',
'http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#processingtype',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productmaterialgroup',
'http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#digitaldetectorresolution')
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
select distinct(t2.graph_id) from quad_text_no_ga t2 where t2.subject = t2.graph_id and t2.
subject_type in ('http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#industry','
http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#xraypanelsize','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#countryregion','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productgroup','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#report','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#salesdocumentstatus','
http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#erppriceitemwhitelist',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#approvalrule',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#triggeraction',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productmrptype',
'http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#processingtype',
'http://www.example.com/application/schema.owl#productmaterialgroup',
'http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#digitaldetectorresolution',
'http://www.example.com/application/products/products-schema.owl#xraypanel')
```

**EXPLAIN for NOT WORKING**

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function - it always applies to all columns in the select list. `distinct (a), b` is exactly the same as `distinct a, b`

Comment: This error message cannot be caused by this query, unless `quad_text_no_ga` is a view with a weird definition or something similar. What is the execution plan that `EXPLAIN` shows you?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe My explain tab is always empty under PgAdmin, is there a way I can enable it ?

Comment: I don't know pgAdmin, but you can simply execute `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` as SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Okay, I have added image in my question.

Comment: You can see the `current_setting` call in the execution plan. Is row level security turned on for the table? If yes, what are the policies?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbeI guess it is trying to find context_info variable which is empty, am I correct? For row level security, may be can you please elaborate more, as I am new to PostgreSQL, trying to convert MSSQL queries to PostgreSQL.